# Google map crashes when version upgraded from 1.9.2 to 1.10.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, ios7

I had used Google map sdk version 1.9.2. But Apple rejected due to crash occuring while rapid zoom in/out. Now I changed the version to 1.10.1. Now my app crashes whenever mapViewController is loaded in my iphone(ios 7) but it works fine in my ipad(ios 8.4). I can't find the reason for the crash.  It crashes soon after viewDidLoad is loaded even if there is no codes in it. Nothing is shown in console window. Is memory leakage is the reason for my crash or anything else? Please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: Try debugging your app. Also use instruments to see the memory usage of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable zombies in Edit Profile -> Run -> Enable zombies objects.